# Codemirror comment.js addon won't uncomment in Ruby mode

Tags: ruby, comments, add-on, codemirror

I'm using codemirror in Ruby mode, with the following includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/codemirror/theme/ambiance.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/codemirror/addon/dialog/dialog.css">
<script src="/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="/codemirror/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
<script src="/codemirror/mode/ruby/ruby.js"></script>
<script src="/codemirror/addon/search/search.js"></script>
<script src="/codemirror/addon/search/searchcursor.js"></script>
<script src="/codemirror/addon/dialog/dialog.js"></script>
<script src="/codemirror/addon/comment/comment.js"></script>
<script src="/codemirror/addon/edit/closebrackets.js"></script>
```

I bound the Cmd-/ and Ctrl-/ keys like so:

```
    'Cmd-/' : 'toggleComment',
    'Ctrl-/' : 'toggleComment'
```

The command works fine on a single line of Ruby (it comments/uncomments the line in toggle fashion). However when I select a block of code it only comments, but does not uncomment the block. Instead of uncommenting, it adds another layer of comment characters (# in Ruby).

Is this a bug? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Update: I just determined that if I select 10 lines and execute the command, they all comment properly. If I then hit the command again, I get more comment characters, as per above. However if I reduce the selection to the first 9 of those same lines, it works! Even the 10th -- unselected -- line is uncommented. Seems like a bug, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, a bug. See https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/commit/9a50176800dfd9f4a5cdc19564a26381e71ed96f for a fix. Bugs are best reported on the issue tracker of that same github repository.

Comment: Thanks. I'll submit anything else I see on github.